# defining a circle by algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've got a 100px*100px image 
Gotta draw some filled circles with random position and radius.the problem is not the random stuff.
I just don't know the algorithm to define a circle with position(x,y) and radius(r) on pixels.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic]: 3.Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer for it:
Midpoint circle algorithm

```
void drawcircle(int x0, int y0, int radius)
{
int x = radius;
int y = 0;
int err = 0;

while (x >= y)
{
    putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y);
    putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x);
    putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x);
    putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y);
    putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
    putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
    putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x);
    putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y);

    if (err <= 0)
    {
        y += 1;
        err += 2*y + 1;
    }
    if (err > 0)
    {
        x -= 1;
        err -= 2*x + 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Be honest and [cite properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#C_EXAMPLE). While it's good that you know what and where to look, presenting the copypasta as your own "cooking" is not good.

Answer (score 0):

the equation you have to apply should be derived from pythagore :

```
 r² = x²+y² 
 r <= 50
```

Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Having just *three points* on the circle's edge you can find both *center* and *radius* of the circle:
let `A, B, C` be the points and `a, b, c` are corresponding *sides* which are (in 2D case)

```
a = Sqrt((Bx - Cx) * (Bx - Cx) + (By - Cy) * (By - Cy));
b = Sqrt((Ax - Cx) * (Ax - Cx) + (Ay - Cy) * (Ay - Cy));
c = Sqrt((Bx - Ax) * (Bx - Ax) + (By - Ay) * (By - Ay));
```

then *radius* `R` is

```
R = a * b * c / Sqrt((a+b+c)*(b+c-a)*(c+a-b)*(a+b-c));
```

Next, let

```
d = (a*a*(b*b+c*c-a*a) + b*b*(c*c+a*a-b*b) + c*c*(a*a+b*b-c*c))
```

the *center* `K` is at

```
K = (a*a*(b*b+c*c-a*a)*A + b*b*(c*c+a*a-b*b)*B + c*c*(a*a+b*b-c*c)*C)/d
```

Having both radius and center you can use circle's equation to define all the points within the circle (2D case):

```
(Kx - x) * (Kx - x) + (Ky - y) * (Ky - y) <= R * R
```

Finally

1. Detect edges
2. Take three points on a edge, find a circle
3. Validate (esp. if circles cross each other)

Comment: Seems convoluted, error prone (special case of 3 collinear points, circle not entirely contained by the rectangle) and CPU-heavy (lots of sqroots and special validations) Why? What am I missing? (it simpler to generate a random radius and then a centre which you know will make the circle contained entirely by the bounding rect)

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi: `Math.Sqrt` is just one `FSQRT` command on FPU so it's not CPU-heavy (there're only *four* square roots per circle). Collinear points special case is easy to avoid; if you don't want to be precize up to the pixel you can skip much of the validations (which are required if you have crossing circles, noised picture etc.). Imagine that you have a picture of an old broken phonograph record and you want to reconstruct its original view (the problem I had to solve) - edges, triangles, circles, validations; finally the most probable circumference.